# data Binding to periodical UserControl

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I have a form, which is used twice, the same UserControl. UserControl has a ListBox, which uses DependencyProperty as ItemSource(ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Persons, ElementName=ThisControl}).

```
    public static readonly DependencyProperty PersonsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register
        (
             "Persons",
             typeof(ObservableCollection<person>),
             typeof(Control),
             new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new ObservableCollection<person>(), OnPersonsChanged)
        );

    public ObservableCollection<person> Persons
    {
        get { return (ObservableCollection<person>)GetValue(PersonsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(PersonsProperty, value); }
    }

    private static void OnPersonsChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var me = sender as Control;
        var old = e.OldValue as ObservableCollection<person>;
        if (old != null) old.CollectionChanged -= me.OnCollectionChanged;
        var n = e.NewValue as ObservableCollection<person>;
        if (n != null) n.CollectionChanged += me.OnCollectionChanged;
    }

    private void OnCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset)
        {
            Persons.Clear();
        }

        if (e.NewItems != null)
        {
            foreach (person item in e.NewItems)
            {
                item.PropertyChanged += OnPersonChanged;
            }
        }

        if (e.OldItems != null)
        {
            foreach (person item in e.OldItems)
            {
                item.PropertyChanged -= OnPersonChanged;
            }
        }
    }

    private void OnPersonChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
    }
```

This UserControl used multiple times. This leads to that the element is added to the collection of one UserControl, it is displayed in all UserControls.
What should I do to prevent this from happening?

Comment: Is this the code behind of your usercontrol?

Comment: The only reason I could figure out is all the instances of usercontrol and in turn Listboxes' ItemsSources are binded to the same collection instance.

Comment: This code describes the property Persons in UserControl

Comment: Why is this so? I have another property that is different for different controls ...

Comment: I have explained in the answer below. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is where you are setting the default value for the Persons, all the instances for Persons will share the same default instance.  you can check the hashcode for each instances.
Don't set the default as `new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new ObservableCollection<person>()` set default to null and check in UserControl's constructor if Persons is null, then instantiate it with `new ObservableCollection<person>()`

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The control is doing it's job properly, its displaying the collection of `Person`s that it has been given, even after the collection has been updated.

Therefore the answer is easy. If you want to display different sets of people, use different collections. You could just copy one by using

```
 var copy = new ObservableCollection<Person>(original);
 userControl1.Persons = original;
 userControl2.Persons = copy;

original.Add(new Person("Me"));
//No change in userControl2
```

Comment: Kind of like when registering property, a new instance of Persons

Comment: new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new ObservableCollection<person>(), OnPersonsChanged)

Comment: ... ie a default value. I do not create Persons in another way